Handling movement on a slope in Unity3D?
I'm just looking for information or resources/tips because I haven't been able to figure it out properly in months.
I have a character controller and when moving up a round surface, the slope angle changes significantly each frame and the angle goes up and down so it's never consistent and so if I want to slow player movement speed when moving up the slope, I can't get it to work because each step the player takes, the angle either remains roughly the same or it goes up/down by 5-10 degrees and sometimes even more, so something like the following will not work at all.
I've even tried angle ranges but there's still or ignoring very small angle changes but there has not been any changes. What happens is the player speed will go up/down/up/down every frame which looks and plays terribly.
if (slopeAngle > 65f)
{ 
    # reduce speed etc
}

Currently I use a BoxCast since it covers more area and is more consistent than both a Raycast and SphereCast and then Vector3.Angle to get the hit.normal and handle the slope movement, and I also push the player down so that there's no bouncing when moving down slopes, etc. But I cannot solve the main issue. Is there any information/tips out there to do with this?

Use a "multiplier" instead of step changes. On level ground, the multiplier would be "1". The speed would then be a function of slope. At 5%, for example, speed (might be): "standard speed" * 5/6; where the "limit" of slope is say 30%. (no one can climb a 65 degree angle "walking"). Slopes are gradual ...which implies an "easing" function while moving over them (from ... to ... over time ... with deceleration and acceleration at the end points).

Do you mean very slightly increasing/decreasing speed over time for as long as I'm on a slope that's steep enough? Wouldn't this also cause "jitter" behaviour since the angle still changes every frame? So even if the speed (default 4) goes up or down by like .5f etc, it would still be noticable? I had a similar approach with Vector3.MoveTowards but I didn't get it quite right

There is a "standard speed"; e.g. 80 yards per minute on level, hard, ground. Instead of "changing speed" outright as conditions change, you instead apply "multipliers"; which vary with conditions. The default for any multiplier is 1.0. As conditions change, the multipliers change, and the properties they affect change. If you're getting "steps", then your steps are "too big" or your frame rate is too slow. One way is to very slowly vary the "slope / speed" multiplier. The paradox is, that the faster you run an animation, the better it looks. It's also "over" faster.

I have also noticed, that animating "thin" objects causes "pixelation" that becomes very noticeable ... so, "softer edges" makes for better animation. (I use "radient" colors)

Yeah I understand the concept now, just definitely not in practice but I'm going to read into what you said a bit more. Would you say that predicting the slope angle in advance via a raycast that casts forward (or spherecast 360 degrees) is a poor solution here?

"All " my animations are based on "predicting". If I'm "climbing" a slope, it's all been part of getting to a particular point; and I've already pre-calculated all the "slope delays" due to contours (on the map). For each "travel leg" I've programmed all the "straights and turns" based on the "movement" (to be) performed (fire and forget). A "monitor" will "interrupt" a movement if it detects a (pending) collision, and launch a "counter" movement (again based on a "odds" prediction). So, "predicting" is more exacting, but answers questions "reacting" doesn't do very well.
